# Can or cannot Sonata News Bundle be used without FOS User Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata

I'm trying to set up my new Sonata based environment, but due to some internal business requirements, we cannot use FOS User Bundle neather Sonata User Bundle.

But I would like to use Sonata News Bundle, however after the initial setup of composer dependency and appKenrnel dependency I noticed a internal bundle dependency:

#### /vendor/sonata-project/news-bundle/Resources/config/admin.xml

```
<services>
    <service id="sonata.news.admin.post" class="%sonata.news.admin.post.class%">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_blog" label="posts"  label_catalogue="%sonata.news.admin.post.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
        <argument />
        <argument>%sonata.news.admin.post.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.news.admin.post.controller%</argument>

        <call method="setUserManager">
            <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />
        </call>
```

#### Error from console after composer install:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   The service "sonata.news.admin.post" has a dependency on a
>   non-existent service "fos_user.user_manager".

Has anybody managed to use News Bundle without FOS User Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this could be possible:

`SonataNewsBundle`refers to `Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface` that extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface`, but this is only Php documentation, so it should work without (or with a dummy one you could write).

Comment: I had to write a dummy empty service configuration defining fos_user.user_manager to make it work....  Don't like it, but fast enough ;)

Comment: Great new! Hate these dependencies